# How to download dynamically loaded links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to download all player images from the premier league website, but have run into a wall.[Link to images](https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/1/Arsenal/squad)
The player image links are all in a tag that looks like the following.

```html
<img data-script="pl_player-image" data-widget="player-image" data-player="p80201" data-size="110x140" 
class="img statCardImg" 
src="https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p80201.png" 
alt="player.name.display}">
```

The problem is that the `src` gets loaded dynamically and so the `request` library don't work, since before the real source is loaded tag contains the following source `https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/Photo-Missing.png`.

I am also unable to replicate all the requests to the resource since I'm unable to find each players unique identifier. I'm aware selenium can be used to solve this problem, but I wonder if there is any library that can pre-load javascript before downloading the DOM, or if there is a better/faster option than selenium to get all the links?

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Ofcourse, my apologies. Added link in post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you want to download images you can use the following trick :)

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/1/Arsenal/squad')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

for img in soup.select('img.statCardImg'):
    player_id = img.get('data-player')
    url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{}.png'.format(player_id)
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open('{}.png'.format(player_id), 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(chunk)
```

since all image url has the same structure you can construct it using the value of `data-player` attribute.

Comment: thank you! I was unable to find the value of each player and thought this was not feasible, thank you for taking your time to provide this!